# How can I make an NSMutableDictionary with Objects as the values?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So right now I have this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *login = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:(const __unsafe_unretained id *) forKeys:<#(const __unsafe_unretained id<NSCopying> *)#> count:<#(NSUInteger)#>]
```

and I want to make the keys be unique (and be able to add/delete) and then have the values be objects, so I can handle the values separate from the dictionary. So then I have another class where I want to have the object created:

```
@interface NewDictionary : NSObject

+(NewDictionary*) newDictionaryWithUsername: (NSString*) username
                        andPassword: (NSString*) password
                           andCount: (int) count;


@end
```

but I'm very lost/stuck. Can you help me proceed? I don't know how to initialize, or create teh objects for the values, or set the values, or modify for that matter

Comment: Take a bit of time to read this and you'll understand everything you just asked (and more!) in no time: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary.html

Comment: I think you're just confused by that declaration (that you presumably extracted from the .h file).  Even [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:) is less confusing.

Comment: (Basically it's `dictionaryWithObjects:obj1, obj2, obj3 andKeys:key1, key2, key3 count: 3`.  And there are other forms that are even simpler.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the object inside you dictionary then try like this:-

```
NSMutableDictionary *login=[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[login setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"username"];
[login setObject:@"xyz" forKey:@"pwd"];
```